# handling String input at runtime in java

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am trying to write a code that takes multiple `Uniprot IDs` for proteins from user and performs further actions on those IDs.

As the `Uniprot ID` consists of 6 letters, I want to implement it so that when the user enter 6 letters, the cursor automatically moves to the next line.

I am using `jTextArea` for taking input.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want want the cursor to automatically finish once you've entered 6 characters?  Is that your problem?

Comment: Could you please show us what have tried? I think it is possible to do this with cursor of `JTextArea` but we need to know you have tried to find some resouece

Comment: and do you want it to submit pieces of input every 6 characters effectively hitting enter, or are you just looking to impliment some sort of word-wrap

Comment: yes, I want it to enter multiple strings, each of length 6. So I want the system to recognize the point when user reaches sixth character, and stops further input in that very same line, but shifts the cursor to next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using **getCaretPosition()** method for textArea. I have implimented this method in constructor for the class, and at a difference of six characters, I have inserted a newline in textarea using following code.

```
int caretPos=jTextArea1.getCaretPosition();
       System.out.println("Caret Position is "+caretPos);
       if(caretPos%7==0){
           jTextArea1.append("\n");
       }
```

It worked for me for the time being, but if someone has better solution, please share it with me.